# Facebook not pulling my og:image images, though it is finding it

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Firstly, I know there is a similar question on SO but this is not a duplicate, as the issue there was different, though observed behaviour is the same.

I have added a few og:image tags and when I run my url through facebook debugger, it is finding the images but showing them as blank.

When I click the blank image tiles, it is showing me the image on the browser, so a little stumped here.

Here is what facebook sees for the images:

```
"image": [
       {
          "url":  "http://[MY_SERVER]/path/to/jpg"
       },
       {
          "url":  "http://[MY_SERVER]/path/to/jpg"
       },
 ],
```

In the debugger section on object properties, under og:image, it is showing two blank tiles. However when I click the tiles, it redirects to the image url on my server and the browser renders the image corretly.

Why is facebook not able to show these images then? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The size of these JPEG images is around 500KB and aspect ratio is 1024X768 (so less than 3:1). For a completely different image that was of size around 100KB and aspect ratio 500X375, facebook was showing the image in the share. Just wondering if there could be an issue with the size of the image?

Answer (score 2):

I find most of my errors can be found using the facebook debug tool at

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Usually you are missing something or you have a duplicate of the same code.